# integer value comparison not working properly

Tags: android, if-statement

I've a string value `String str="Success"`

How to check the "str" value is not equal to "Success". If I try `if(str!="Success")`. It is not working properly.

I've a integer value `int a=250` If I use `If(a!=250)` this is also not working properly.

How to code for these conditional statements ? I'm using Android and Eclipse version 2.1.

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As every one said, String values should compare with `.equals` method.

like

```
if(str.equals("Success"))
{
    System.out.println("My String is Success");
}
```

Next coming to integer comparison.

As you have said, you have the integer value

```
int a=250

if(a!=250)
{
   // Some code
}
```

Here already your a value is 250. then you are executing some lines of code if `a` value is `not equal` to 250. Then how the condition will execute. if you want to test then

change the a value and then check again as

```
int a=50

if(a!=250)
{
   // Some code===============> Now this code will execute
}
```

Comment: s u r right, but i execute this code at runtime. i got this "a" value is given by server.

Comment: then are you getting any problem with the condition..if so post the block of code you are using. i think you are missing some thing there

Comment: if((test!=28)||(test!=29))          test=test+8;   this is what i have. test is integer value. if i debug the code will not execute properly . i dint know y

Comment: so you need to stop the message handler when test values is 28 or 29 right

Comment: i got the result. what i learn was dont use OR statement when u compare integer value. thanks

Answer (score 1):

a!=250 should work. 
For string try str.equals("Success")

Answer (score 0):

For string comparison, use the standard `String.equals()` method.

`str.equals("Success");` - For Equals

`if(!str.equals("Success"))` - For Not Equals(your case)

And for **int**, what is being used, is proper. `a!=250` will return `false` in your case. Hence, it'll not enter the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to study Java first ;)
This is not the way to do a String comparison. For String comparison, you must use .equals(String) method.

```
String str1 = "str1";
String str2 = "str2";

if(str1.equals(str2)) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not compare strings with != or =. That won't work in most cases.

```
new String("test").equals("test")
```

Should be used for comparison.

`!=` compares the value and is true if they are NOT equal.

you could also use something like `if(a == 250){...}`

Comment: Not(new String("test").equals("test"))

Answer (score 0):

In Java you cannot use == to compare Strings, you must use:

if(string.equals("example"))

So let's use equals() in your conditional and optimize it:
if(!str.equals("Success"))
this will work

Comment: how to check for integer value.?

Comment: you can use the same to compare integer too..or use == to compare two integers.